# How to add an options menu to the menu Button

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I want to add a menu on the left click.
Where to read about how to do this?

[image: for this button]

Here is the menu

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 3");
}


public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Action 1") {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Action 1 invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (item.getTitle() == "Action 2") {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Action 2 invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (item.getTitle() == "Action 3") {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Action 3 invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now I deduce it by pressing the button in the Activiti

```
 Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        registerForContextMenu(btn);
```

And I want to display when user click on a selection button in the image.

How to do it?

Comment: can you please explain more what exactly do you need? your question's title, picture and description are so confusing...

Comment: I guess he wants to show an optionsmenu

Comment: I update image.

Comment: Why put a minus four? I said something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can find information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu).

I think you are looking for an options menu.
But above Android 3.0 the context menu is in the actionbar.

Comment: No, not the actionbar. I want to display the menu by pressing the specified button